# Accessign results of ThreadPoolExecutor from outisde a fucntion in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrent.futures

So, I am writing a script for checking links in a WordPress post..for that, I am using threading to check multiple links inside various posts(there are many). So, I have 3 functions for that

```
def getStatusCode(link, headers, timeout=5):
        r = requests.head(link, headers=headers, timeout=timeout)
        return str(r.status_code)

def executeBrokenLinkCheck(links):
    tasks = []
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        tasks.append(executor.map(getStatusCode, links, headers))
    return tasks

for i in range(pages):
    post_data = requests.get('https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page='+str(i+1), headers=headers).json()
    for data in post_data:
        print(data["link"])
        post_links = getLinks(data["content"]["rendered"])
        checked_urls = executeBrokenLinkCheck(post_links)
```

Now, I want to get the status codes for all links in a current post from the `for` loop in the `checked_urls` variable.

But I can't seem to make it work. I have googled and looked for other thread and haven't found implementation of concurrent.futures like this...what I am doing wrong. When I print the value of `checked_urls`, I get this:

```
[<generator object Executor.map.<locals>.result_iterator at 0x7f6c1914b610>]
```

But instead I need a list of status codes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a single `executor` that you pass around.
2. For performance, use a single `requests.Session` too.
3. Crucially, call `task.result()` to wait for the actual result of an execution future.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

import requests

headers = {
    # ...
}

sess = requests.Session()


def getStatusCode(link, headers, timeout=5):
    r = sess.head(link, headers=headers, timeout=timeout)
    return str(r.status_code)


def executeBrokenLinkCheck(executor, links):
    tasks = executor.map(getStatusCode, links, headers)
    return [task.result() for task in tasks]


def check_page(executor, page_index):
    post_data = sess.get(
        f'https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page={page_index + 1}',
        headers=headers,
    ).json()
    for data in post_data:
        print(data["link"])
        post_links = getLinks(data["content"]["rendered"])
        checked_urls = executeBrokenLinkCheck(executor, post_links)


def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        for i in range(pages):
            check_page(executor, i)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But it still doesn't work i am afraid. Here the full script and error output: https://paste.ee/p/iAvJR

Comment: "doesn't work" – what happens?

Comment: AttributeError you can see in the pastee link... @AKX

Comment: Get rid of the headers parameters then - you have that name as a global.

Comment: It still errors, AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'result' at line 32 But okay... i have modified the code a bit from your solution and my script works. Thanks for the help though.